# How to write xsl template for such code?

Tags: xml, xslt

XML snippet

```
<para><place>Cape Town</place> Some 150 penguins unaffected by the oil spill began their long swim from Port Elizabeth in the Eastern Cape back to their breeding habitat at Robben Island near Cape Town on Wednesday.</para>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="company">
 <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>    


<xsl:for-each select="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:if test="place">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="place" />
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hi I've been written .xsl file to .xml and I got stack. When I run this code I see only code inside 
place element and the rest of the text is being ignored. Could you give me some tips, please?

Comment: Could you add the desired output and put a more complete XML? E.g. the company tag is missing.

Comment: It should be place instead of company. XML code is on the top. Below its code from .xsl file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="place">
   <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="place" />
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your goal is not clearly stated, but the code above should give you the idea. I've left the company part bacause your example does not include one.